# How do I display large numbers with commas? HTML

Tags: html

I am wanting to display large numbers more nicely with commas. So if the number was say 123456789, it would display 123,456,789. I have looked around but I only found code that just wouldn't work the way I wanted so I was hoping I could find some help here. Also, I hope it is also dynamic, so the commas will change as the number changes.

The number that I want to affect has the id="value".

That should be all, I don't think I am missing anything. So again I want the number with an id="value" to have commas introduced when it's needed. If you need any more information please let me know!

Comment: @michaelpri I just checked that out, and tried using the first comments code and it does not work. I don't understand how to take that and apply it to my code to make it take the right number.

Comment: The question was asked purely in HTML terms. Yet a JavaScript answer has been accepted. The correct answer to the question *as asked* is that you simply need to enter the number in the desired format in HTML. If the question was meant to be about modifying HTML content in JavaScript, it should have been closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was answered here:

[How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

In case you're not interested in reading the answer above, the code given was this:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

If you're using jquery use something like:

```
var val = parseInt($('#value').text());
//Use the code in the answer above to replace the commas.
val = numberWithCommas(val);
$('#value').text(val);
```

Comment: I'm sure this would work but I don't know what to do with it. You gave me two codes but say use the second one, then in the second one say use the first one. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: The first part of code is just the function you will use to separate into commas. The second code is what does the actual job of changing your value to a value filled with commas. note that the  answer given by @Jiri Kremser is actually pretty great. Consider it

Comment: I'm still not getting any results, should I have changed something in the code?

Comment: Okay, I see. It does work, however not how I want it. That only works if the number is stationary and placed there as a large number. It will not work if the number is changing.

Comment: Use an input field. When the value of that input changes, run the function. Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/lrojas94/k9dac6x4/1/

Comment: No idea what an input field is or how to use it.

Answer (score 75):

You can use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
num.toLocaleString('en', {useGrouping:true})
```

Comment: This should be the answer!

Answer (score 17):

There's a simpler syntax for [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
Number(x).toLocaleString();
```

This lets you drop the number in as a variable instead of converting the number into an object.

Comment: 1) numbers **are** objects in javascript; 2) if it's a variable that's already a number, you don't need to reconvert it, `x.toLocaleString()` will work fine; and 3) if you are using a literal, parentheses are plenty `(1234567.456).toLocaleString()`